# how does entrySet in hashmap get created and modified?

Tags: java

```
/**
 * Holds cached entrySet(). Note that AbstractMap fields are used
 * for keySet() and values().
 */
transient Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet;
```

I find a strange thing in java Hashmap. I find no code to create an instance of and manipulate entrySet in hashmap source code and AbstractMap code. But when I put key-value in hashmap, the entrySet gets the new value. It's strange.

So my question is:

how does entrySet gets the new value, and when does it get its instance?

To be more clear, I added my debug code in IDE and find before my first call of this set, it is already not null and filled with elements.

[image]

[image: map]

Comment: Hey, it sounds like you're asking two distinct questions, please make a seperate question to ask about how inner classes work. This question can be for how the entrySet gets the instance.

Comment: please specify the java version you're asking about, these things change sometimes (for example in jdk 12 there is no such a field)

Comment: @MarkBramnik it's jdk8;

Answer (score 2):

This `entrySet` field is set when the `entrySet()` method is called. See the source code of [`entrySet()` in OpenJDK 8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l980):

```
public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet() {
    Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> es;
    return (es = entrySet) == null ? (entrySet = new EntrySet()) : es;
}
```

Also check the inner `EntrySet` class which is directly below the method in the linked source code.

Answer (score 2):

> How does entrySet gets the new value, and when does it get its instance?

The instance of entrySet is created the first time Map.entrySet() is called.

We can see that in the source code of [HashMap](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l996):

```
 public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet() {

        Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> es;

        return (es = entrySet) == null ? (entrySet = new EntrySet()) : es;

    }


    final class EntrySet extends AbstractSet<Map.Entry<K,V>> {

        public final int size()                 { return size; }

        public final void clear()               { HashMap.this.clear(); }

        public final Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> iterator() {

            return new EntryIterator();

        }

        public final boolean contains(Object o) {

            if (!(o instanceof Map.Entry))

                return false;

            Map.Entry<?,?> e = (Map.Entry<?,?>) o;

            Object key = e.getKey();

            Node<K,V> candidate = getNode(hash(key), key);

            return candidate != null && candidate.equals(e);

        }

        public final boolean remove(Object o) {

            if (o instanceof Map.Entry) {

                Map.Entry<?,?> e = (Map.Entry<?,?>) o;

                Object key = e.getKey();

                Object value = e.getValue();

                return removeNode(hash(key), key, value, true, true) != null;

            }

            return false;

        }

        public final Spliterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> spliterator() {

            return new EntrySpliterator<>(HashMap.this, 0, -1, 0, 0);

        }

        public final void forEach(Consumer<? super Map.Entry<K,V>> action) {

            Node<K,V>[] tab;

            if (action == null)

                throw new NullPointerException();

            if (size > 0 && (tab = table) != null) {

                int mc = modCount;

                for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; ++i) {

                    for (Node<K,V> e = tab[i]; e != null; e = e.next)

                        action.accept(e);

                }

                if (modCount != mc)

                    throw new ConcurrentModificationException();

            }

        }

    }
```

The `EntrySet` class is just a set of methods that act on the internal `HashMap`. Therefore, the `EntrySet` holds no information, it's just a view on the data of the `HashMap`.

Answer (score 1):

`Map.entrySet` will just give you a view of the `Map` as a `Set<Map.Entry<,>>`. It doesn't copy the data structure. `List.subList` is the same. `Arrays.asList` should be an easy example to understand.

In Java inner classes have two (or more) `this`s (assuming they are not local classes in a static context). In Python, by convention, `self` is used for `this`. (I haven't done that much Python.) So any methods of inner class would be hiding the outer self. You would have to use different names, and of course be explicit every time you use them. In Java, if you are not explicit, it'll pick the `this` that fits (which can be weird in corner cases).

Comment: But there is a different point in the HashMap case to List.subList and Arrays.asList. It is the latter two both hold a reference to the parent list or to the array, but in hashmap there is nothing and that's the most confusing part. I think the this and method explanation is correct. I modified the question and added some key points which confused me .

Answer (score 0):

The map entry set gets it's value on first request.
This is the implementation of HashMap.entrySet():

```
    public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet() {
            Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> es;
            return (es = entrySet) == null ? (entrySet = new EntrySet()) : es;
    }
```

It is initially null (and transient) simply so safe memory when not needed.

This has not much to do with the nested status of it's classes. It's simply a lazily initialized member variable.